# Searching strings from file in second file in python

Tags: python, string

I'm doing my first steps into python and I have one problem with it. I want to open two files one is 4kB and the second one is 11 MB. First ( smaller ) file looks like this:

```
ABCDE
FGDTR
DTRDG
DRTYJ
ARTYF
```

and the second one is more like:

```
 33.492513889    9.217400000  ABCDE YYYY XX 2118994
 16.000000000  -30.000000000  CJSIA YYYY XX 2115145
 17.000000000  -30.000000000  OALXM YYYY XX 2115145
 18.000000000  -30.000000000  DRTYJ YYYY XX 2115145
```

As you can see first values are coordinates first are latitudes second ones are longitudes. I want to find strings from first file in second file, and create file with all results ( named e.x. done.txt ) in this format:

```
XXXXX;LATITUDE;LONGITUDE;
```

Where XXXXX is string from file one.

Thanks for any advises

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far, with a code example? Remember, StackOverflow is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: Will there be duplicate values in the first file?

Comment: Yes second file contains multiple values but I want to have them even if they are duplicated.

Comment: But the first file? The answer I wrote won't work if the first file has duplicates but will be okay if the second file has duplicates.

Comment: And yes I tried searching in stack overflow questions about that but none of them helped me. I'm really not into programming but I have around 600 values to find copy and write and dont want to do it manually :/ . I tried also making it I node but it didnt worked.

Comment: First file doesn't contain duplicatea

Answer (score 0):

A file object in python is basically a generator. You can open it and iterate over it line by line using a `for` loop.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

For your problem, my approach would be to store all the *words* from the first file into a `set`. (for faster membership operations)

Open the second file and read each line from it. Split the line and extract the `strings` from the line and check if it's in the `set`. If it is, then the first file has that string and you can write it in the required format in your output file.

I don't want to write the code for you and you should do it yourself. But this would be my approach.

As a side note, you can open multiple files using `with`.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('done.txt', 'w') as output:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks I dont want to people write my code I wanted from beginning to do it myself but I wanted just help from somebody :) thanks I will try

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of formatting, the functionality could be easily achieved with Pandas.

The 2nd file should be properly formatted as a CSV. I took your input and formatted it as below with some header fields as below:

```
Latitute    Longitude   Indicator   someColumn1 someColumn2 someInteger
33.492513889    9.217400000 ABCDE   YYYY    XX  2118994
16.000000000    -30.000000000   CJSIA   YYYY    XX  2115145
17.000000000    -30.000000000   OALXM   YYYY    XX  2115145
18.000000000    -30.000000000   DRTYJ   YYYY    XX  2115145
```

NOTE: I am using \t->tab as a delimiter

The program itself is very simple:

```
import pandas as pd

toSearch= []
with open('firstFile.txt', 'r') as fd:
    toSearch= fd.read().split('\n')

df = pd.read_csv('secondFile.txt', delimiter='\t')

df[df['Indicator'].isin(inputs)][['Indicator', 'Latitute', 'Longitude']].to_csv('output.txt', index=False)
```

If you dont want to use pandas, still we can achieve it by going through line by line and searching for the string.

```
toSearch= []
with open('firstFile.txt', 'r') as fd:
    toSearch= fd.read().split('\n')
with open('secondFile.txt', 'r') as fd, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    while fd:
        line = fd.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line_words =  line.split('\t')
        if line_words[2] in toSearch:
                   fout.write({}\t{}\t{}\n".format(line_words[2],line_words[0],line_words[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

open your first and second file with `open("file_name.extantion",'mode')` and then read data

```
first_obj = open('first.txt','r')
second_obj = open('second.txt','r')

first_obj.close()
second_obj.close()

f_file = first_obj.read().split('\n')
s_file = second_obj.read().split('\n')
```

then you can check for each string of f_file to be matched with in a line of s_file

```
for string in f_file:
    for line in s_file:
        if string in line:
            lat_long = ' '.join(line.split()[0:2])
            final = open('done.txt','a+')
            final.write(string+' '+lat_long+'\n')
            final.close()
```

Dont't forget to close files after operation safely or you can use `with` statement also